# Android - Parsed an incomplete JSON response

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using Volley JSON request to parse a JSON from a web service.

This is how it looks like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "category": "Wallet",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/1718946498/60284_1389592558.4e549bae0384ffce63035a7689d824c4_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/1718946498/60284_1389592558.4e549bae0384ffce63035a7689d824c4_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "166",
            "shop_vanity": "EProductsSibu",
            "description": "DESCRIPTION: Good Leather. Made in India.\r\n\r\nPACKAGE CONTENT: Good Condition\r\n\r\nREASON FOR SALE: One more extra\r\n\r\nCOD LOCATION: Sibu, Sarawak",
            "item_id": "18319",
            "name": "Always Wild Men's Wallet With Chain Ring",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:56:01",
            "category_friendly": "wallet",
            "user_id": "60284"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589673.a4bc91735db236661b207534e72849bb_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589673.a4bc91735db236661b207534e72849bb_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)\r\n\r\n",
            "item_id": "18307",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589678.8c60ab80a3eea04dc74605d3e4df2d8b_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589678.8c60ab80a3eea04dc74605d3e4df2d8b_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)",
            "item_id": "18308",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589683.1b19cc2dedfde693784e8cd915b45227_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589683.1b19cc2dedfde693784e8cd915b45227_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)",
            "item_id": "18309",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589687.93389c64d7e36d7ebfaf58dbbb77914a_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589687.93389c64d7e36d7ebfaf58dbbb77914a_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)",
            "item_id": "18310",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589692.21d560bc5aec0e594bfc1598b9c8f3ca_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589692.21d560bc5aec0e594bfc1598b9c8f3ca_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)",
            "item_id": "18311",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        },
        {
            "category": "Accessories",
            "thumbnail": {
                "image50": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589697.01e964c85afb4a2b1e8caf2bcf5ad169_50.jpg",
                "image100": "http://ked.ai/uploads/item/656783513/1802_1389589697.01e964c85afb4a2b1e8caf2bcf5ad169_100.jpg"
            },
            "price": "10",
            "shop_vanity": "mhs",
            "description": "BROOCH CINCIN SESUAI DIPAKAI OLEH MEREKA YG GEMAR BERTUDUNG BAWAL. BOLEH MENJIMATKAN MASA SEKALIGUS TAMPAK ANGGUN ;)",
            "item_id": "18312",
            "name": "Brooch Cincin",
            "created_at": "2014-01-13 13:10:19",
            "category_friendly": "accessories",
            "user_id": "1802"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I got an incomplete JSON response. Only **the first two** results objects was successfully parsed. Here is the method for parsing the json:

```
private void loadItemList() {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");

    String url = Constants.LATEST_ITEM_LIST;

    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                    parseJSON(response);
                    va.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());

                    errorMsg = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error,
                            getActivity());

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    mRequestQueue.add(jr);
}

private void parseJSON(JSONObject json) {
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject itemlist = items.getJSONObject(i);

                ItemListModel ilm = new ItemListModel();
                ilm.setCategory(itemlist.optString(Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_NAME));
                ilm.setItem_id(itemlist.optString(Constants.TAG_ITEM_ID));
                ilm.setName(itemlist.optString(Constants.TAG_ITEM_NAME));
                ilm.setPrice(itemlist.optString(Constants.TAG_ITEM_PRICE));
                ilm.setUser_id(itemlist.optString(Constants.TAG_USER_ID));

                JSONObject thumb = itemlist.getJSONObject(Constants.TAG_ITEM_THUMBNAIL);
                ilm.setThumbnail(thumb.optString(Constants.TAG_ITEM_THUMB));

                arrItemList.add(ilm);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Item list: ", "null");
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my logic above?

Comment: It's always better to use GSON or JACKSON lib for JSON parsing, you are using efficient lib volley why are you using manual old method for JSON parsing? create POJOs and start using GSON lib!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have parsed your json array like

```
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("results");
```

So in your for loop instead of using ***json*** Object you must use your ***items*** JsonArray. So from that you can access your other data which is containing by it.

So change from

```
  for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
```

to

```
  for (int i = 0; i < items .length(); i++)
```

Comment: Haha, small mistake. THank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

because your getting length from **JSONObject** as `json.length();` for your for loop you need to get the length from `items.length();` **JSONArray** not from **JSONObject**

```
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your For loop you have defined the array size of your `json` Object not your `JsonArray` may that is why its not giving proper result.

take the size of your `items` JsonArray in your for loop like `items.length()`.

Try out as below:

```
    JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
```